# How to adjust a Java animation in real time?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe, jpanel

I have created a simple animation in which a square bounces from corner to corner. However, it only does this within a fixed range. If I adjust the frame size, it still only bounces within the range. How do I change the bounds in real time so if the window is stretched the shape will still animate across the entire window?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
int x=0, xspeed=2,y=0,yspeed=2,framex=575,framey=575;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    timer.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(x<0||x>framex){xspeed=-xspeed;}
    if(y<0||y>framey){yspeed=-yspeed;}

    x=x+xspeed;
    y=y+yspeed;
    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Animation a = new Animation();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animate");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(a);
}
}
```

Comment: paintComponent is sometimes called *many times per second.*  Do not start a Timer in that method, and do not perform any logic other than what is needed to draw your component.  It is, however, safe to restart a timer from an actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(x<0||x>framex){xspeed=-xspeed;}
if(y<0||y>framey){yspeed=-yspeed;}
```

You get the current size of the panel using the getSize() method.

```
Dimension d = getSize();

if(x < 0 || x > d.width){xspeed =- xspeed;}

if(y < 0 || y > d.height){yspeed =- yspeed;}
```

Don't be afraid to use white space to make your code more readable.